# Regex for FIGI numbers

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write some regex to match FIGI numbers.

FIGI numbers have 12 characters and are built in the following structure:

- A two-letter prefix, excluding (BS, BM, GG, GB, GH, KY, VG)
- G as the third character
- An eight character alpha-numeric code which does not contain English vowels "A", "E", "I", "O", or "U"
- A single check digit (0-9)

E.G.

`BBG000BLNNV0` is a valid FIGI

I have already:
`^([A-Z]{2})(G{1})(([A-Z]|\d){8})\d{1}`

But I am unsure on how to add the **exclusions** e.g. not including any vowels and not including these specific letter combinations: `BS, BM, GG, GB, GH, KY, VG`

Anyone have any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would write the exclusions with a negative lookahead/behind.  Adding a simple negative lookahead for the two letter prefix to your existing regex would look like this.

```
^(?!BS|BM|GG|GB|GH|KY|VG)([A-Z]{2})G(([A-Z]|\d){8})\d{1}
```

But it could be shortened a little by grouping together some common sets

```
^(?!B[SM]|G[GBH]|KY|VG)([A-Z]{2})G(([A-Z]|\d){8})\d{1}
```

I also shortened `(G{1})` to just `G` because it's the same thing, unless you need the capture group.  `{1}` had no effect at all.

Lastly, the not-vowels.  Again, using a negative lookahead and utilizing the `\w` metacharacter (which is alphanumeric plus an underscore).

```
^(?!B[SM]|G[GBH]|KY|VG)([A-Z]{2})G((?![AEIOU_])\w){8}\d
```

Just an aside, you could replace the second negative lookahead with a positive lookahead, in combination with a negated character class.

```
^(?!B[SM]|G[GBH]|KY|VG)([A-Z]{2})G((?=[^AEIOU_])\w){8}\d
```

Comment: Yes perfect, you missed the B in the G letters, (G[GBH]) but a very nice and clean solution. What is the benefit of adding a second negative lookahead with a positive lookahead?

Comment: Thanks, I made the correction.  There second negative lookahead is functionally the same as the positive lookahead in this case; though the former matches in fewer steps.  If you try them on regex101, it tells you how many steps it took to match.  Mostly, I was just demonstrating two different ways to do the same thing with different types of lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `DEFINE` as in:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<prefix>(?:B[SM]|G[GBH]|KY|VG)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[A-Z]{2})
    (?<no_vowels>(?:(?![AEIOU])[A-Z0-9]){8})
    (?<digit>[0-9])
)
^
(?&prefix)
G
(?&no_vowels)
(?&digit)
$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/N6Ry98/2/).